Is this simple implementation of Mutex in typescript correct?
In our application, my colleague implemented a Mutex class that exposes a runExclusive API. However, our app occasionally suffers from deadlocks. I don’t fully understand the promise mechanism behind it that handles this functionality.
Could anyone guide me through it and help identify which part might be causing the issue?
export interface MutexInterface {
  lock(): Promise<() => void>;
  runExclusive<T>(cb: () => Promise<T>): Promise<T>;
}

export class Mutex implements MutexInterface {
  private mutex = Promise.resolve();

  /**
   * @description acquire lock to lock the mutex.
   * @returns A function that unlocks the mutex.
   */
  async lock(): Promise<() => void> {
    let begin: (unlock: () => void) => void;

    this.mutex = this.mutex.then(() => new Promise(begin));

    return new Promise(res => {
      begin = res;
    });
  }

  /**
   * @param callback A function that returns a Promise.
   * @returns A Promise that resolves to the value returned by the callback.
   */
  async runExclusive<T>(callback: () => Promise<T>): Promise<T> {
    const unlock = await this.lock();
    try {
      return await callback();
    } finally {
      unlock();
    }
  }
}


Expect no deadlock to occured. But the function calling runExclusive will hang forever unless I restart the app.
